# Fadeout not fading, just disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to make a stacked animation where I will use delay to gradually fade elements out. The problem is, the elements aren't fading. I have several elements that are display:none to start, then using FadeIn to bring them in. They don't fade though, they just pop in. That's no good.

The catalyst for the animation is the a.engine link. When thats clicked, the animation starts by removing a class from the background image (gives it a blur and changes the opacity), and then the various elements fade in. Eventually I want it to automatically scroll down to an anchor, but I'll figure that out in a bit. For now, its just the lack of fading thats got me confused.

Here is the code I am using.

```
    $(function () {
        $("a.engine").click(function () {
            $("img.bg").removeClass("intro_effects").delay(500);
        $("h4.fade_out").delay(200).fadeOut("slow");
        $("h4.fadein").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
            $("div.menu_container").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
            $("div.main_content").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
        $(".parallax1").delay(200).queue(function () {
                $(this).css("display", "block")
            });  
        });
```

The site itself is here: http://dev.mediaslave.ca/illustraflex

Is there a reason the fades aren't fading? Maybe in combo with the other animations or something?

Comment: Please post the relative css and html to help everyone out a bit.

Comment: I didn't post all the CSS and code purposefully, since there are quite a few elements. None of it is tricky though, just lengthy. I am hoping theres either a rule on stacked animations that I don't know, or that I'm missing something in the jQuery that somebody will spot. 

If it will help I'll post it all, but its just elements with display:none on them, then the code above was supposed to fade them in.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try removing the css last? The reason is that the fadeIn method manipulates an elements opactiy. If you already have opacity as part of the element, maybe that is interfering with the fadeIn animation.

Comment: I actualy removed that altogether, and it didn't change anything at all. For some reason the little fadeOut items still just pop in. Its so frustrating!